# JUnit fails when run two tests with same variable name execute

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, junit, jodatime

I have written the following tests for my classes:

```
import org.junit.After;
import org.joda.time.LocalDateTime;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

public class ScheduleUnitTest {
    private DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm");

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        // Available 8:00 - 18:00
        // Break 12:00 - 12:30
        Schedule schedule = new Schedule();
        ScheduleElement element;

        element = new ScheduleElement();
        element.setType(EventType.AVAILABLE);
        element.setBegin(getDate("20-08-2014 08:00"));
        element.setEnd(getDate("20-08-2014 18:00"));
        schedule.addElement(element);

        element = new ScheduleElement();
        element.setType(EventType.UNAVAILABLE);
        element.setBegin(getDate("20-08-2014 12:00"));
        element.setEnd(getDate("20-08-2014 12:30"));
        schedule.addElement(element);

        schedule.make();

        assertThat(schedule.isAvailable(getDate("20-08-2014 12:10"), getDate("20-08-2014 12:20"))).isFalse();
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() {
        // Available 8:00 - 18:00
        // Break 12:00 - 12:30
        Schedule schedule = new Schedule();
        ScheduleElement element;

        element = new ScheduleElement();
        element.setType(EventType.AVAILABLE);
        element.setBegin(getDate("20-08-2014 08:00"));
        element.setEnd(getDate("20-08-2014 18:00"));
        schedule.addElement(element);

        element = new ScheduleElement();
        element.setType(EventType.UNAVAILABLE);
        element.setBegin(getDate("20-08-2014 12:00"));
        element.setEnd(getDate("20-08-2014 13:30"));
        schedule.addElement(element);

        element = new ScheduleElement();
        element.setType(EventType.AVAILABLE);
        element.setBegin(getDate("20-08-2014 12:30"));
        element.setEnd(getDate("20-08-2014 13:30"));
        schedule.addElement(element);

        schedule.make();

        assertThat(schedule.isAvailable(getDate("20-08-2014 12:10"), getDate("20-08-2014 12:20"))).isFalse();
    }

    private LocalDateTime getDate(String date) {
        return LocalDateTime.parse(date, formatter);
    }

}
```

When I run both tests, then one of them always fails. It says:

```
test2(org.example.ScheduleUnitTest)  Time elapsed: 0.011 sec  <<< FAILURE!
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<[fals]e> but was:<[tru]e>
```

But when I run both separately, then both tests pass. The solution is to change name of `Schedule schedule = new Schedule();` for `schedule1` and `schedule2`. Then, once again, both pass.

Why does it work like that?

**EDIT**
Here is source code for the `Schedule` class:

```
import org.joda.time.LocalDateTime;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class Schedule {

    private List<ScheduleElement> elements = new ArrayList<ScheduleElement>();

    public void make() {
        // sorted ASC
        Collections.sort(elements, new Comparator<ScheduleElement>() {
            public int compare(ScheduleElement o1, ScheduleElement o2) {
                return o2.getCreated().compareTo(o1.getCreated());
            }
        });
    }

    public boolean isAvailable(LocalDateTime begin, LocalDateTime end) {
        for(ScheduleElement scheduleElement : elements) {
            if(scheduleElement.isOccurring(begin, end)) {
                if(scheduleElement.getType() == EventType.AVAILABLE) {
                    if(!begin.isBefore(scheduleElement.getBegin()) && !end.isAfter(scheduleElement.getEnd())) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }

                return false;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public boolean isOccurring(LocalDateTime date, EventType type) {
        for(ScheduleElement scheduleElement : elements) {
            if(scheduleElement.isOccurring(date, type)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public void dates(LocalDateTime begin, LocalDateTime end) {

    }

    public void dates(LocalDateTime begin, LocalDateTime end, EventType eventType) {

    }

    public void addElement(ScheduleElement element) {
        elements.add(element);
    }

    public List<ScheduleElement> getElements() {
        return elements;
    }

    public void setElements(List<ScheduleElement> elements) {
        this.elements = elements;
    }
}
```

**SOLVED**

The problem was somewhere else: `schedule.make()` has `Collections.sort`. It sorted array in wrong way. `ScheduleElement` has property

```
private LocalDateTime created = LocalDateTime.now();
```

And often it doesn't mean if I put `element = new ScheduleElement()`; one by one, then I mean that order `created` is different, but not. I need to set up property manually, and then it works.

I'm sorry for that!

Comment: If you run both tests are they ran parallely ?

Comment: I suspect that you have mutable static data in your `Schedule` class. Would you mind adding the source code for `Schedule`?

Comment: @entpnerd different variable names would have no effect in this case.

Comment: @Antoniossss probably yes. Just run mvn test or IntelliJ Debug for class.

Comment: @entpnerd I added source code for Schedule class. Could you look on it?

Comment: Please, add the code for `ScheduleElement`, so anybody can try to reproduce this issue

Comment: `DateTimeFormatter formatter` maybe is not thread-safe. This is the case in old java SimpleDateFormatter, and repaired in the java 8 LocalDateTime. Create dynamically a DateTimeFormatter and see wether that solves things. When so, switch to java 8 LocalDateTime.

Comment: @JoopEggen yes, it's something wrong with threads. Answer below works but I don't know why. I use Joda LocalDateTime and documentation says: "LocalDateTime is thread-safe and immutable, provided that the Chronology is as well. All standard Chronology classes supplied are thread-safe and immutable.".

Answer (score 4):

I don't think that the code for `Schedule` is the problem, because you are instantiating it locally within the test, and there is no static data to share between threads. I believe that the problem may be your date parsing in the test class, itself, which gets executed in parallel when the tests run together in parallel. Try the following change to `getDate()`::

```
private LocalDateTime getDate(String date) {
    synchronized (LocalDateTime.class) {
        return LocalDateTime.parse(date, formatter);
    }
}
```

This will ensure that no two calls to `parse()` occur in parallel within your JVM.

Comment: It works! Thanks :) Why Joda LocalDateTime is not thread-safe? Documentation says something else [link](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDateTime.html)

Comment: I just checked the source code (http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/time/LocalDateTime.java#LocalDateTime.parse%28java.lang.CharSequence%2Cjava.time.format.DateTimeFormatter%29). The problem isn't actually that the `LocalDateTime` class, itself, is thread safe. Rather, the `DateTimeFormatter` instance that you are passing is not thread safe. You need to compensate for this. Once fix is my fix in the answer, but you could also create a new `DateTimeFormatter` instance for each test, too.

Answer (score 0):

make the following changes to the unit test, thins might fix your problem.

- Add a `@Before` method(`setup`) and initialize `schedule` inside that.

So the test becomes something like this..

```
private Schedule schedule;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    schedule = new Schedule();
}

@Test
public void test1() {
   // setting values go here.

     schedule.make();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying it before, but doesn't work. Same problem as described above.